# Why does `Is Clustered` show as No for a AG SQL Node?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I am looking at a primary node of SQL AG, configured with sync auto-failover, no read scale.

When I open the `Server Dashboard` report, it shows the `Is Clustered` value as No.

Why does `Is Clustered` show as `No` for a AG SQL Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install the SQL Server as a Failover Clustered Instance then SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') returns 1 / Your Server Dashboard show 1.

When you have Always On Availability Groups, you install your SQL Server instances as Stand Alone instances.